# trying to understand php syntax. what does this mean? ( $joker == 1 && $this->has_jokers ) $score *= $joker_multiplier;

Tags: php

I am learning php syntax but I get stuck when things like this come up:

```
if ( $joker == 1 && $this->has_jokers ) $score *= $joker_multiplier;
```

what does each part mean?

Comment: You stuck with which part? all of it?

Comment: If `$joker` equals `1` and `$this->has_jokers` then `$score` equals `$joker_multiplier` times its previous value.

Comment: See this documentation will completely help for you [php_operators](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but,

- $joker is a variable
- $joker == 1 return true if $joker is 1.
- $this->has_joker means has_joker is an attribute of the class you are in.
- $score *= $joker_multiplier, is the same as $score = $score*$joker_multiplier, white multiplier being another variable probably defined earlier.

> By the way it only multiplies if $joker is 1 and has_jokers is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $joker == 1 && $this->has_jokers )
```

- When value of `$joker` variable is `1` and value of `$this->has_jokers` evaluates to `true`, then the if condition succeeds

---

```
$score *= $joker_multiplier;
```

- It is otherwise written as `$score = $score * $joker_multiplier;`
- So, `$score` variable is replaced (previous value is replaced) with the `$score` value multiplied with `$joker_multiplier` value

---

### **tl;dr**

When you have joker and its only one, you are multiplying the score with value initialized in `$joker_multiplier` variable

Answer (score 0):

IF the variable named $jokers is equal to 1 AND the property has_jokers of the object named $this is TRUE, THEN set the variable named $score to the current value of $score multiplied by the variable named $joker_multiplier.